# How to get a new DF column from iterating over two other Dataframes columns?

Tags: pandas, loops, dataframe

I have two dataframes df1,df2. df1['A'] holds a list of words. df2['b'] holds couple of words. I need to have a separate df3 where I need to say how many words of df['b'] are there in df1['A'].

I am new to python and the solution I have is a very inelegant 'for loop' in which I am iterating over the words of df1['A'] and iterating over words of df2['b'] and checking and setting a count. 
I believe there are better and faster ways to achieve this. Can anyone please point me in the right direction? 
****Update**** 
Sorry about the unclear question. Following is a representation of what i am trying to achieve. 
[data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pp2Qc.png)

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please share some sample data

Comment: Do they have to be in the same row ?   What happens if a word appears twice in df2['b'] do you count it once or twice ?  Can you provide sample of code please

Comment: Do the columns have the same length?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think for your benefit you should start looking into function calls.  Although they scale terribly with the amount of data being processed, in your case, the performance is probably negligible.

```
'''
Create a dataframe from the cartesian product of two other dataframes:

    df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [['red apples', 'ripe oranges'],
                              ['ripe mangoes', 'unripe pineapple']]})

    df2 = pd.DataFrame({'b': ['apples, mangoes', 'grapes, mangoes, pineapple']})
    p = [[x[0], y[0]] for x,y in product(df1.values.tolist(), df2.values.tolist())]

    df = pd.DataFrame(p)
'''

def get_counts(row):
    return sum(1 for item in row[1].split(', ') for thing in row[0] if item in thing)

df['count'] = df.apply(get_counts, axis=1)

print(df)
```

You could also do:

```
df[1] = df[1].str.split(', ').apply(set)
df[0] = df[0].str.join(' ').str.split()
df['count'] = df.apply(lambda x: x[1].intersection(x[0]), axis=1).apply(len)
```

If you want just the count,

```
#As series: 
df = df['count']

#As dataframe:
df = df[['count']]
```

Comment: Thank you. I put in the columns for df3 for it to be clearer. I dont want the two columns in the third dataframe. Just the count. So to function, i would esstentially need to pass the row of df1 and row of df2 . I did that with  for loop. Any python way to do the same? thanks

Comment: Depends how you want the output really, this doesn't really need to be done with pandas, FYI, but it's good to learn from.  I edited my answer.